# How can i name an automatic ec2 snapshot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot

I have this code being run daily on task scheduler:

```
{

$Description = Date -format dd-MM-yyyy

new-ec2snapshot "vol-bcd03793" $Description

}
```

But when the snapshot is created, the name is left blank. Of course you can go in and give it a name yourself, but how can i automate this part of the process?

!!UPDATE!!
Here is the simple solution to the problem:

```
{

            $Description = Date -format dd-MM-yyyy
            $snapshot = new-ec2snapshot "snapshot volume id here" $Description

            $tag = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Tag
            $tag.Key = "Name"
            $tag.Value = "Name of snapshot"

            New-ec2tag -ResourceId $snapshot.SnapshotId -Tags $tag

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add the name of the snapshot with tags [ Name:MySnapshot1 ]. I looked at the api for the snapshot creation [ec2-create-snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-CreateSnapshot.html) but there isn't an option to specify the tag; but however describe snapshot [ec2-describe-snapshots](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeSnapshots.html) can be filtered by tags.

So the approach would be to,

1. Create Snapshot, get the resource ID - snapshot ID [ec2-create-snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-CreateSnapshot.html)
2. Then do modify the tag of the Snapshot as a EC2 Resource [ec2-create-tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-CreateTags.html) -
   **[ Key:Value - Name: ]**

Comment: Naveen, I actually managed to solve this problem myself although I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Slight change to save create a new Tag object

```
$Description = Date -format dd-MM-yyyy
$SnapName = "Name of snapshot"
$VolId = "Volume ID"

$snapshot = New-EC2Snapshot -VolumeID $VolID -Description $SnapDescription

New-ec2tag -ResourceId $snapshot.SnapshotId -Tag @{Key="Name"; Value=$SnapName}
```